# Type 'NSObject?' has no subscript members

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swift3, macos-sierra

I've already searched and really, asking a question on here was my last resort... honestly, *but feel free to downvote the heck out of me since "I had to ask"...!* now down to business...

I have a dictionary with two levels "dict > keys", that's it! but for whatever reason that I can't seem to get the "three" value out. Where did I go wrong here?

```
print(mainDict)

/*
 ["keys": {
     one = "one...";
     two = 2;
     three = "three"; // need this one!
 }]
*/

let sub = mainDict["keys"]
print(sub as Any)

/*
 Optional({
     one = "one...";
     two = 2;
     three = "three";
 })
*/
```

Great! so far so good... but then:

```
let keyThree = mainDict["three"]
print(keyThree as Any)
// nil

let keyThree = sub["three"]
// Type 'NSObject?' has no subscript members
```

WTH? ... TRIED:

- [Why do I have "type 'NSObject' has no subscript members" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36172362/why-do-i-have-type-nsobject-has-no-subscript-members-error)
- [[NSObject : AnyObject]?' does not have a member named 'subscript' in Xcode 6 Beta 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25495092/nsobject-anyobject-does-not-have-a-member-named-subscript-in-xcode-6-bet)

Comment: please share the initialization of the dictionary

Comment: @AmrElAdawy: `func makeThisPossible(mainDict: [String : NSObject])`

Comment: share the code where you set the values initially

Comment: @Russell: You mean `let mainDict = (userInfo as? [String: NSObject])!` ?, the function that is called from is `optional func application(_ application: NSApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [String : Any])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration of `mainDict` in the function signature has to be `[String :[String:Any]]`. Or you can declare it as `[String:Any]` and then, you need to cast the sub as `[String:Any]`

So the function should be

```
func makeItPossible(mainDict : [String:Any]){
   if let sub= mainDict["keys"] as [String:Any], let keyThree = sub["three"]{
        print(keyThree)
}
```

Updated to use conditional binding.

Comment: I was written almost same.. . **Instead of force unwrapping use conditional binding** to extract the values..

Comment: Hi Kumar, Please propose an update to my answer as another code block. I'd review and accept.

Comment: @KumarKL: Care to explain why to use conditional over forced?

Comment: To overcome the crashes, when force unwrapping fails then app crashes so ..